# Duplicate key in Hibernate JPA OneTOMany save operation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

This is my Item class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "demo_transaction")
@Transactional
public class Item {
    @Id
    Integer item_id;
    String itemName;
    Integer price;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Event> events;
```

Event class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event", schema = "demo_transaction")
@Transactional
public class Event {
    @Id
    Integer event_id;
String eventName;
```

As shown  Item can have multiple Events. In typical SQL an FK table would be like this:

```
item_id event_id
1       10
1       20
2       10 
2       20
```

But when I am trying to save these I am getting constrain violation.

```
    Event e1=new Event(10,"FirstEvent");
    Event e2=new Event(20,"SecondEvent");
List<Event> lse1=new ArrayList<>();
        lse1.add(e1);
        lse1.add(e2);
        Item item1 = new Item(1,"FirstItem",600,lse1);
List<Event> lse2=new ArrayList<>();
        lse1.add(e1);
        lse1.add(e2);
        Item item2 = new Item(2,"SecondItem",200,lse2);
repo.save(item1);repo.save(item2);
```

> I understand that since eventId is the primary key and I am trying to save
> twice that's where the constraint getting violated but how would I
> achieve that FK table? Please help

Comment: auto genrated id is ok for your problem?

Comment: Not an issue. I just turned it off since I am saving manually.

Comment: You can auto generate ids as below

Comment: I want generate the FK table in the given format

Comment: From your table, what you are looking for is `ManyToMany` relationship not `OneToMany`. If it's a `OneToMany`, an event cannot have two `item_id`s.

Comment: @Dejazmach So you are saying same event_id can't be shared by multiple item_ids?Can you please provide a full solution ?

Comment: Exactly, you can search `ManyToMany` jpa implementation on the internet. It's everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible with a OneToMany configuration. An item can have many events, but an event can only have one item. You are trying to add the same event to multiple items.

```
postgres=# \d item_events;
                 Table "public.item_events"
     Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 item_item_id    | integer |           | not null | 
 events_event_id | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "uk_nvp3wmby13pbecx8ikeoae9ep" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (events_event_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk98kk1sdgqem8j50mo5avvvmg5" FOREIGN KEY (events_event_id) REFERENCES event(event_id)
    "fkovh11t671qjb2w11sxos7ktvo" FOREIGN KEY (item_item_id) REFERENCES item(item_id)
```

As you can see the unidirectional OneToMany creates a join table, item_events, and the event_id column has a unique constraint on it to ensure an event can only belong to one item. Without this the relationship becomes a ManyToMany. If you want to add the same event to multiple items you will have to configure the ManyToMany relationship in your entities.

Answer (score 0):

@`GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Add above annotaion to the event_id and item_id. Then it wiil generate unique ids for you.

Then add @JoinColumn(name = "item_id") to event_id field and mappedBy = "item" to inside of OneToMany of the item_id field .Also have to add @ManyToOne for event_id field.
You can do bidirectional OneToMany mapping as follows.

```
  //for Item change as folllows

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer item_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch= FetchType.EAGER 
     ,mappedBy = "item")
    List<Event> events;
    
        // for Event change as follows

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer event_id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    Item item;
```

Comment: Unique ids are not issue the FK table is not getting generated

Comment: On which filed in Event I need add @JoinColumn?

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception. Can you fully edit your answer, please? In code I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248322/discussion-between-yjr-and-suvam-roy).

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException